# why is this vuex computed getter not reactive?

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

```js
<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const playlists = computed(() => store.getters.allPlaylists);
    ...
    store.dispatch("playlists/getAllPlaylists");
```

```js
// modules/playlists

const state = () => ({
  all: [],
})

// getters
const getters = {
  allPlaylists: (state) => state.all,
  ...

const actions = {
  getAllPlaylists: ({ commit }) => { // api calls performing setPlaylists mutation
  commit('setPlaylists', playlists)
  ...

const mutations = {
  setPlaylists: (state, playlists) => {
    state.all = playlists;
  },
  ...

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

`playlists` in the component turns out to be empty.
if I use `const playlists = computed(() => store.state.all);` instead it works, am I doing something wrong?

it is because the getter is a function?
if I should use `store.state.all` instead, what's the use of getters?

added store:

```js
import { createStore, createLogger } from 'vuex'
import mediafiles from './modules/mediafiles'
import playlists from './modules/playlists'

const debug = import.meta.env.DEV

const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    mediafiles,
    playlists
  },
  strict: debug,
  plugins: debug ? [createLogger()] : []
})

export default store
```

Comment: How are you calling createStore?

Comment: @PalashBansal added

Comment: You need to pass the getters and state to the createStore, are you doing that?

Comment: @PalashBansal yes, I added the return code in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the module getters with `store.getters` because that's the root getters.
Instead, try to do it similar to how you are calling dispatch:

```js
    const playlists = computed(() => store.getters['playlists/allPlaylists']);
```

For details see the comments in the namespacing sample in the official documentation for modules: https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing